# Updating GLIBC, building cross-GCC, getting `bad ELF interpreter'

Tags: c, linux, ld

I am trying to workaround an outdated GLIBC on a computer without root rights. The OS is CentOS 6.

As I understand, I need a full-blown cross-GCC to be set up for compiling programs using GLIBC_2.14 symbol. I have found and followed this set of advices (using `--target=x86_64-redhat-linux`)

https://preshing.com/20141119/how-to-build-a-gcc-cross-compiler/

and I've ended up with working GCC. But I am concerned because of this:

```
$ ldd ~/opt/cross/bin/gcc-cross
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00002aaaaaacb000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00002aaaaaccd000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002aaaaafd3000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00002aaaab258000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002aaaab46e000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002aaaaaaab000)
```

This `ldd` is the system one, but I have a brand new GLIBC! Let's try it out:

```
$ ~/opt/cross/x86_64-redhat-linux/bin/ldd ~/opt/cross/bin/gcc-cross
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00002aaaaaacb000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00002aaaaaccd000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002aaaaafd3000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00002aaaab258000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002aaaab46e000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002aaaaaaab000)
```

Okay, these are identical. Lets compile a test program:

```
$ cat testc.c  
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
        printf("Hello, world!\n");
}
```

Command

```
$ gcc-cross -Wl,--rpath=~/opt/cross/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib -Wl,--dynamic-linker=~/opt/cross/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 testc.c
testc.c:3:1: warning: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
 main()
 ^
```

With system `ldd` I get

```
$ ldd a.out
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00002aaaaaacb000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002aaaaaccd000)
    ~/opt/cross/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002aaaaaaab000)
```

but with my `ldd` I end up with error

```
$ ~/opt/cross/x86_64-redhat-linux/bin/ldd a.out                    
/home/user/opt/cross/x86_64-redhat-linux/bin/ldd: ./a.out: ~/opt/cross/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

and it fails with the new glibc's runner as well:

```
$ ~/opt/cross/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 a.out
a.out: error while loading shared libraries: a.out: cannot open shared object file
```

I expected this `a.out` to be linked against new glibc and that this fact can be seen through `ldd` (and that this program will fail at ordinary run `./a.out` and will print "Hello, world!" with that new runner). Moreover, I wanted to get a compiler that links to the new GLIBC automatically without these -Wl,--blah-blah words.

I'm afraid that I do not understand what I am actually doing, so I will be very glad if you explain this a little bit more detailed.

---

**Edit 1 after comments.**
Okay, this tilde totally got me :) But dome questions are still there. Now it says

```
$ ldd a.out 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00002aaaaaacb000)
    libc.so.6 => /home/user/opt/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00002aaaaaccd000)
    /home/user/opt/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002aaaaaaab000)
```

As I understand, `libc` is now linked properly, but what about `ld-linux`? Why does `/lib64/ld-linux` still appear and why does new `ld-linux` still fail?

```
$ ~/opt/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 a.out
a.out: error while loading shared libraries: a.out: cannot open shared object file
```

Comment: "As I understand, I need a full-blown cross-GCC" No you absolutely totally don't. If you want to update gcc, just build an updated gcc, not a cross-compiler. If you want to update glibc, just build an updated glibc. If you want to build against your new glibc with your new compiler, or your old compiler, just do so. Nothing cross required.

Comment: shell does not perform tilde expansion in the middle of a string, and therefore the tilde in your -Wl,--dynamic-linker argument stays as-is. You have to expand it manually (or use $HOME).

Comment: Edited to reflect these comments.